# Showing image/icon over components

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, image

I'm using react, and I have an icon which is an image, the issue is that the position of it is fixed, it's showing and working normally as I want except when scrolling to another component such as carousel or cards, you can see from the pics, how can I fix this?

[This is how it's shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4NgG.png)

[This what happens when user scrolls to another component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoVrn.png)

Comment: The pictures are helpful, but please include code snippets as well so we can see what is going on. Without being able to see the code, my best guess at a solution would be the z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use z-index

You should give the z-index of the icon div higher than the z-index of the carousel or card div

example

```
`.icon{z-index:99999,position:'fixed'}`
<div class='icon'>your icon<div>
```